# WPF combo box binding to generic list

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox

I have a method which returns a generic list (from the db it returns a set of data to a list). I want to bind one property of that list to a `ComboBox` using `ComboBox`'s  `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListFirstName}"` property.  How can I achive this? The code I tried:

XAML code:

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbName"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ExamineeList}"
         DisplayMemberPath="FirstName" />
```

XAML.cs code:

```
Examinee oExaminee = new Examinee();
List<Examinee> ExamineeList;
ExamineeList = oExaminee.ListAll(); //ListAll method returns a generic list 
cmbName.DataContext = ExamineeList;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're setting the ComboBox's DataContext to your list of Examinees in code, but then your XAML is trying to set its ItemsSource to a property called "ExamineeList". Since `List<Examinee>` has no property called "ExamineeList", the binding is not succeeding.

To tell the ComboBox to bind directly to its own DataContext, you can remove the Path from the binding:

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbName"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          DisplayMemberPath="FirstName" />
```